# Intent — transferring a button tag?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I have a borderless button on in one of my layouts. When it is clicked, I want the intent to transfer both the button's tag and the text it contains. I am having trouble doing this.

This is what I have for when the button is clicked:

```
public void openGoalWeek (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewGoal.class);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.week_goal);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, button.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString(EXTRA_TAG, button.getTag().toString());
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is what I have in the `ViewGoal` class:

```
public class ViewGoal extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_goal);

        // make sure running on honeycomb or higher for actionbar API
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        // get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getBundleExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE).toString();
        String tag = intent.getBundleExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TAG).toString();

        String text = "null";

        if (tag == "year_tag") {
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            Goal goal = db.getYearGoal(message);
            text = goal._title + "\n" + goal._description;
        }

        if (tag == "month_tag") {
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            MonthGoal goal = db.getMonthGoal(message);
            text = goal._title + "\n" + goal._description;
        }

        if (tag == "week_tag") {
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            WeekGoal goal = db.getWeekGoal(message);
            text = goal._title + "\n" + goal._description;
        }

        // create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(10);
        textView.setText(text);

        // display the content
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

It throws an error at me and I am not sure why. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What error? Post the logcat file.

Comment: Okay, I have gotten rid of the error. I didn't have the tags set correctly in the xml file. But now when I run the application, it doesn't change the string text. It just stays at null, even though one of the if statements is true.

Comment: Put Log.i("TAG", variable); in if condition. So you will get to know actual value of that tag u r trying to set.

Comment: Okay so the problem is that the if statements are not executing. If I place the "Log.i("TAG", variable);" inside the if statements, nothing gets outputted. If I place it outside of them, it prints out the tag. For example, I just ran it, the tag was "year", the Log.i statement printed out the tag, however the if statement was not executed. I believe I set it up correctly?

Comment: Change the statements as if (tag.equals(nameOfString)) or if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(nameOfString)). == doesn't work for String.

Comment: I can't believe I made that mistake. I am a beginner haha. Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just do this, just put your EXTRA instead of using bundle:

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewGoal.class);
intent.putExtra( EXTRA_MESSAGE, button.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra( EXTRA_TAG, button.getTag().toString());
....
```

Later on in the other activity:

```
....
// get the message from the intent
Intent intent = getIntent();
String id   = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String name = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TAG);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

In onClick button, instead of this used `classname.this`
Some of my errors are removed by this. Try if it helps you.

```
public void openGoalWeek (View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(className.this, ViewGoal.class);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.week_goal);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, button.getText().toString());
bundle.putString(EXTRA_TAG, button.getTag().toString());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```